# When i tried to a insert a row, it give me Error Code:1452

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`comments` (
  `comment_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iduser` INT NOT NULL,
  `datePosted` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `comments` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  `idgame` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `comments_id_UNIQUE` (`comment_id`),
  INDEX `comment_user_id_idx` (`iduser`),
  INDEX `comment_game_id_idx` (`idgame`),
  CONSTRAINT `comment_user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`iduser`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `comment_game_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idgame`)
    REFERENCES `game_review`.`games` (`game_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_review`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is the action:

```
INSERT INTO game_review.comments (iduser,datePosted,comments,idgame) VALUES(1,NOW(),"dsds",1)
```

This is the response:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`game_review`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comment_game_id` FOREIGN KEY (`idgame`) REFERENCES `games` (`game_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a game with id 1 stored in your `games` table, that's why you get the error since the comments table has a FK pointing to that table.

Comment: I see :) i will go try putting something in to games table

Comment: By the way, can u explain to me what does this FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 about? I searched in youtube for solution for the error 1452 earlier on and i saw this

Comment: It's a setting that removes the check on foreign keys when set to 0. So if you apply it your insert would work and you can insert the game afterwards but this should be a temporary workaround if you can't solve it any other way. Better to do things in the right order.